# Exercise 1.1.27 in Tao's Topics in Random Matrices (moments and convergence)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

[image]

I'm stuck on parts (iii) and (iv). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Answer for 1v): $X_n=nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$ on $(0,1)$ with Len=besgue measure. The answre to iii) is somewhat lengthy and I don 't what results are allowed to be used here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What is X in your example? $0$?

Comment: In my example $X=0$. In fact $X_n \to 0$ almost surely (which implies convergence in distribution).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: As for what we are allowed to use, I think the most relevant is the Portmanteau theorem which is covered right before this exercise, and basic results from measure theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kavi Rama Murthy gave a good counterexample for $(iv)$ in the comments. Let me give a relatively short argument for $(iii)$.

First, note that by the result of $(ii)$ it is enough to show that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^k] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|^k].$$

Now, you can check that for any $K$, $f: x \mapsto |x|^k 1_{\{|x|^k \leq K\}}$ is bounded and upper-semicontinuous and so by the Portmanteau theorem we have that
$$\limsup \mathbb{E}[ |X_n|^k 1_{\{|X_n|^k \leq K\}}] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|^k].$$

Also, by Holder's inequality, you get that
$$\mathbb{E}[ |X_n|^k 1_{\{|X_n|^k > K\}}] \leq \mathbb{E}[ |X_n|^{k + \varepsilon}]^{\frac{k}{k+\varepsilon}} \mathbb{P}( |X_n|^k > K)^\frac{\varepsilon}{k + \varepsilon} \leq K^{- \frac{\varepsilon}{k}} \sup_n \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^{k + \varepsilon}]  $$
where I have deduced the last inequality by writing $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|^k > K) = \mathbb{P}(|X_n|^{k + \varepsilon} > K^\frac{k + \varepsilon}{k})$ and applying Markov's inequality.

Hence
\begin{align*}
\limsup \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^k] \leq& \limsup \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^k 1_{\{|X_n|^k \leq K\}}] + \limsup \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^k 1_{\{|X_n|^k > K\}}]
\\ \leq & \mathbb{E}[|X|^k] + K^{-\frac{\varepsilon}{k}} \sup_n \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^{k+ \varepsilon}].
\end{align*}
It then follows that $\limsup \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^k] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X|^k]$ by sending $K \to \infty$ in the above inequality.